# click() not working in selenium headless python (But also doesn't throw any error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to `.click()` on the like button of Instagram Post by using `.find_element_by_xpath('//section/span/button[*[local-name()='svg']/@aria-label='Like']')` in headless mode.

The code is working properly when I run it without headless but when I run on headless it doesn't throw any errors, executing the whole code but the thing is, **it's not liking the post either**. Any Solutions on this behavior?

Comment: Sometimes a change like running in headless can trip bot detection, particularly a site like instagram that wants to try to avoid 'like' bots. What would be occurring in this case is that instagram is getting the like click, but throwing a captcha afterward that you can't see because you're in headless. Selenium correctly says the like was clicked, but having not performed the captcha, the 'like' doesn't register with IG.

Comment: But we don't see the captcha while not in headless? Is there something in particular that causes captcha to only occur in headless? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Captcha and bot detection are, by design, actively and purposely hiding how they work and what methods are being used. It exists for the sole purpose of stopping you from doing what you're trying to do. People do get around it, but it's a game of cat and mouse, and those who have found a way around don't usually share what they know - or that they know - because when they do, captcha and bot detection for sites change in response. You're trying to do something and other people are actively trying to stop you from doing it.

Comment: A simple example, though, would be this: Javascript can detect the size of your window - it's used a lot for normal web design. It can also detect movement of the mouse pointer, etc. A standard headless driver likely doesn't bother faking a reasonable window size and certainly doesn't move your pointer around for you, so a website like IG can see that your window  is 0px by 0px, for example, and flag it as likely bot activity - throwing a captcha.